# How do I determine the length of an "array of structs" in a DBus message?

Tags: c, ipc, dbus

I'm using the [libdbus API](http://dbus.freedesktop.org/doc/api/html/group__DBusMessage.html) to send method calls and receive replies. For one such method I am expecting a reply of the format:

`"a(sqns)"`

Which in DBus signature notation means: an array of structs, where the contents of each struct is a string, uint16, int16, and string.

Using a [`DBusMessageIter`](http://dbus.freedesktop.org/doc/api/html/group__DBusMessage.html#ga9f98b47c84f0e401ea985e681de4e963) (iterator), I can iterate through the array and structs.  However, to simplify my parsing code, is there a way I can get the length of this array before iterating through?

Unfortunately I don't believe [`dbus_message_iter_get_fixed_array`](http://dbus.freedesktop.org/doc/api/html/group__DBusMessage.html#gae195a3312ae445e7ef0196854f3523f8) applies in this case because my array contains structs which by this definition appears to mean [non-fixed size](http://dbus.freedesktop.org/doc/api/html/group__DBusSignature.html#ga2f89962cbd33e4ad843824157bae2093).

It is not immediately apparent to me from the API doc how to do this (or if it's possible).

Comment: It is pretty likely that it is just stored in a dynamically allocated `struct *` array with the last element being a `NULL` ptr. I would say that there is probably no way without iterating over the entire list.

Answer (score 1):

A bit late to the party maybe but for future reference, I've had success using `dbus_message_iter_get_element_count()`. You can use it like so:

```
int count = dbus_message_iter_get_element_count(iter);
if(count > 0) {
  DBusMessageIter arriter;
  dbus_message_iter_recurse(iter, &arriter);
  for(int i = 0; i < count; ++i) {
    // read items from arriter
  }
}
dbus_message_iter_next(iter);
```